# How to fetch the first post when the last in reached in will_paginate and Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate

I have a bunch of posts, and I'd like to always show 3 per page. Say I have 4 posts, as follows:

```
post 1
post 2
post 3
post 4
```

If I use will_paginate (or really any pagination plugin), with 3 results per page, page 1 will contain:

```
post 1
post 2
post 3
```

And page 2 will contain

```
post 4
```

I'd like to make it so that page one will contain post 1, 2, and 3, and page two will loop back to the beginning, as such:

```
post 4
post 1
post 2
```

How do I achieve that?
Thanks!

Comment: What should be displayed in page 3? Is it `[3, 4, 1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WillPaginate actually lets you define the collection it uses directly with `WillPaginate::Collection.create`. I think a bit of code like the following should do the trick:

```rb
@posts = Post.offset((page - 1) * per_page).limit(per_page)
post_count = @posts.count
if post_count < per_page
  @posts = @posts.all + Post.limit(per_page - post_count).all
end

# At this point you have an array of posts. 
# Now we create the WillPaginate::Collection so will_paginate will work.

@posts = WillPaginate::Collection.create(page, per_page) do |pager|
  pager.replace(@posts)
  pager.total_entries = Post.count
  pager
end
```

Comment: You still need to set the current page, otherwise the pagination will not work.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu Yes, obviously, I'm assuming the `page` and `per_page` variables are set for this solution.

Comment: What I mean is the `current_page` accessor within the `WillPaginate::Collection` class needs to be reset on the last page back to the first page if the user wants to recycle back to the first page.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu The `current_page` of the collection is set by the argument given to the `create` method, so any looping that has to be done just involves manipulating that argument before passing it.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using kaminari instead of will_paginate -- it's WAY more flexible (although it doesn't have a built in method for doing this). But this DOES answer the questions and I really appreciate the answer!

Comment: @yuval I just checked out kaminari, and it looks like it may solve some problems I've always had with `will_paginate`. So thanks to you too!